# Java Concurrency Threading Error

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I have a list of 100 strings. For each string I need to perform 3 tasks.
So I introduced Concurrent threads

```
Class A implements Runnable
{

  String str;
  A(String s)
  {
    str = s;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args)
   {
     Runnable runnable = null;

      //For Each of my strings
      for(String s:MyList)
      {
          runnable = new A(s);
          new Thread(runnable).start();
      }
  }

   @Override
   public void run() {
       task1();
       task2();
       task3();
   }
 }
```

This Runs into an Exception.

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
Exception in thread "Thread-0" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

How do I overcome this and restrict the Thread size?

I tried Using this.

```
ExecutorService pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
pool.execute(runnable);
```

It doesnt work.

Comment: Are you creating a new threadpool for every iteration?

Comment: You should go back to trying to make your `ExecutorService` version work. Because that's the more reasonable way to run 100 asynchronous tasks.

Answer (score 3):

"java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space" means pretty much exactly what it says - the heap (the place you allocate new Java objects from) is out of space.  Not sure what you are doing in those tasks but it must be using a lot of memory.

You can either figure out what is taking up so much memory and reduce it.  Or you can - as you mention - reduce the number of concurrent operations, which would presumably use less memory.  Or you can use something like:

```
java -Xmx1024M A
```

To manually specify the amount of memory made available to the JVM.  But note that just increasing the memory limit without understanding why it's using so much memory is not a good idea.  I would suggest looking for a bug in these taskN() calls first.

Comment: Thank you! I will check it out. Yes! Each task does take a lot of time since they reach out to an API like 300 times for each thread. That was the reason I went for multithreading since single thread was taking annoyingly huge amount of time